# Laravel validation errors not shown only for images

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am struggling to display errors after image validation failed. Seems strange but I don't know why I can `dd($errors->first('profile_picture)` and it works (I see the error) but I cannot `{{ $errors->first('profile_picture) }}`. I am using the default Laravel piece of code to display errors, for example, under email field:

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Just replace `email` with `profile_picture`. Can't understand what happens.

Comment: what is the output of <?php print_r($errors->all()); ?> ? and check that key exists or not.

Comment: Here is the output: Array ( [0] => The profile picture may not be greater than 2048 kilobytes. )

Comment: can you please check css class invalid-feedback ? you must did some mistake on css side.

Comment: It is from Bootstrap 4. I haven't touched it. In fact, it works for bad email formatting, for example. It is the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. The error message got `display: none` for a mysterious reason. I hacked it to `display: block` in my custom CSS and it works. Idk... Thanks, anyway :)

Comment: Oh… missed it in the doc. Well… thank you so much! I won’t forget it!